# Where to look for systemd-networkd device names?

Tags: linux, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I'm running Debian Jessie/8.2 on an ARM single board computer with `systemd`. I'd like to entertain using `systemd-networkd` instead of the `ifup` mechanisms. One of the apparent steps, is to figure out the name of network device(s) for use in the `.network` files in the `[Match]:Name` fields. Some examples call these en0 and en1, so on. I'm not sure where to look to confirm what my devices are identified as on this board. Where does one figure out what they will be on a given board. About the only thing I've found so far is

```
root@nelson:/etc/network/interfaces.d# dmesg | grep eth
[   14.770000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.080000] macb f0028000.ethernet eth0: link up (1000/Full)
[   16.080000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   19.030000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   20.220000] macb f802c000.ethernet eth1: link up (10/Half)
[   20.220000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[142442.240000] macb f0028000.ethernet eth0: link down
[231513.370000] macb f0028000.ethernet eth0: link up (1000/Full)
[231517.370000] macb f0028000.ethernet eth0: link down
[231519.370000] macb f0028000.ethernet eth0: link up (1000/Full)
```

Is one of these the name I should be placing in my .network files? Would it be `eth0` and `eth1` or `f0028000.ethernet` and `f802c000.ethernet`? Or something somewhere else. I think I saw something related to udev, but I haven't been able to find any rules or anything related to this (my /etc/udev/rules.d is empty).

As an aside, the default version of systemd for Jessie seems to be 215. Is this even an advisable thing to try (converting to networkd)?

Also, should this question be in SuperUser instead? Couldn't come up with better tags for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from the helpful #systemd irc channel.

```
/sys/class/net
```

All of the devices show up there by the name systemd-networkd will consume them.